# simplefunge - NilClass error even when top of stack is not null

Tags: null

**CODE:**

```
91+I-v
     V
     O
     @
```

I made this code for a PPCG (Programming Puzzles and Code Golf) submission, but it is not working.

The error code it returns is `/opt/simplefunge/simplefunge.rb:53:in <main>': undefined methodord' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Wow, does no one know simplefunge here?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. Are you using the latest version from github? According to the error and https://github.com/Aearnus/simplefunge/blob/master/simplefunge.rb#L53 your class STDIN.getc doesn't exist (is nil) while trying to access STDIN.getc.ord.

Comment: @relet I am using tio.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code expects input from stdin with the I command. 
If you do not provide input, tio.run provides an empty list. What the error message tells you is that the interpreter could not transform the empty input (nil) into a numeric value through the ord operation, which is defined for characters.

This can be reproduced locally as:

```
$ echo -n | ruby simplefunge.rb test.funge 
Traceback (most recent call last):
simplefunge.rb:53:in `<main>': undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

To solve this first issue, provide input.

You will get a similar error from the O command in your code, as the previous V operation moves you outside the stack limits, again resulting in trying to apply a character operation on nil when you try to print the stack value as character:

```
simplefunge.rb:57:in `<main>': undefined method `chr' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```